# Attach object to core data model in different contexts

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

First I would like to say that I know we should not mix contexts at all when dealing with Core Data. But I have a peculiar problem that many probably have been through too.

I have an object, created and managed with background context but I want to "attach" an object to it (let say, a category for example) that was loaded in the main context. Therefore I will have the error stating that it's illegal and all.

I would like to know what is the best way to do that stuff and what I am doing incorrect.

Example Code:

```
@IBAction func unwindToAdEdit(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SubCategoryTableViewController, let categoryObject = sourceViewController.selectedCategory {

            // ad was created with insertNewObject backgroundContext
            // category was fetched using main context 
            ad?.adCategory = categoryObject

    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the objectID to the background context and refresh the object in the background context.  Then set the relationship using two background objects.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the answer, but is this the correct/expected/best approach on this? I'm not sure exactly about that.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Don't be afraid to fetch the object again. It is not that costly.

Comment: Nice. That was exactly my concern. Thank you very much, Jon.